# Trying to convert data in one column from string to integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `df['code']` which looks like this.

```
0          1
1          2
2          3
3          6
4          9
5         12
6         15
```

in which the first column are indexes and the second one is the column I wanted to convert to integers.

What I tried to do is:
`for i in range(len(df['code'])):
    df['code'][i] = int(df['code'][i])`

which did not work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: df['columns'].astype(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way to do this would be:

```
for i in range(len(df['code'])):
    df['code'].iloc[i] = int(df['code'].iloc[i] )
```

Instead of using the index itself, it uses the index position.